# change the order of an array to match the order of a set of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I am doing some html5 / jquery drag and drop functionalities to reorder a set of DOM elements. I now want to change an array of objects that correspond to these DOM elements, but I'm not quite sure how to do it. Here's the javascript:

```
var draggedIndex = $('.segmentListItem').index($(draggedItem));
var targetIndex = $('.segmentListItem').index($(this));
var playlist = jwplayer().getPlaylist(); //MH - the array for which I want to change the order

if (draggedIndex > targetIndex){
    $(draggedItem).insertBefore($(this));
    //MH - need to move the playlist item at the index of the dragged item before index the target item as well
} else {
    $(draggedItem).insertAfter($(this));
    //MH - need to move the playlist item at the index of the dragged item before index the target item as well

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If playlist is a regular array, not an object (you are reffering to it as an array), maybe something like this:

```
Array.prototype.move = function (old_index, new_index) {
    if (new_index >= this.length) {
        var k = new_index - this.length;
        while ((k--) + 1) {
            this.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    this.splice(new_index, 0, this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
};

var draggedIndex = $('.segmentListItem').index($(draggedItem));
var targetIndex = $('.segmentListItem').index($(this));
var playlist = jwplayer().getPlaylist(); //MH - the array for which I want to change the order

if (draggedIndex > targetIndex){
    $(draggedItem).insertBefore($(this));
    playlist.move(draggedIndex, targetIndex);
} else {
    $(draggedItem).insertAfter($(this));
    playlist.move(draggedIndex, targetIndex);
}
```